# data gridview with arrow keys using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010, arrow-keys

In vb.net 2010:

I have two `Datagridviews` on a `windows form`.

when I click on the row of `datagridview1`, it shows the fetched result from the database in the `datagridview2`.

so far it is working fine.

but when I scroll through `datagridview1` using arrow keys `up/down`, the function doesn't work and error is shown..

`index out of range.`

Need to know how to select rows in `Datagriview1` using arrow keys and show the result in the second grid view.

thanks

Comment: P.S.--- I am using windows forms with vb.net

Comment: would be better if you show some codes you have ..

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
   private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```